# Salesforce QuickActionsDefaultsHandler - how to make it do nothing when conditions are not met

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-quickaction, casefeed

I am hoping you could assist.  I am currently trying to implement the QuickActionsDefaults handler in our Org so that the template and the Org-Wide email is automatically selected when a user clicks email from the case feed.  At the moment I am trying to make this work from Case type and I do have it have it working.

If a case type is assigned I can have it change the template and the org-wide email.  When testing this in our sandbox environment though - if a case doesn't have a case type associated,  I can't make it "do nothing" or basically not insert a template and have the from address as the users address.  Instead the error - ***you can't perform this action on this page*** is displayed (picture below).

I have pasted my code below.  Could you please suggest what I could do to cover of this scenario, it would be most appreciated.

'''global class EmailPublisherForCaseType implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
    // Empty constructor
    global EmailPublisherForCaseType() {
    }

```
// The main interface method
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(0);
EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject(); 

Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Type FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];    

// If case type is “Bonds,” insert the email template and set the from address
if (c.CaseNumber != null && c.Type.equals('Brand1')) { 
    sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId('00X0I000001GQfdUAG');   // Set the template Id
    sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
    sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);
    emailMessage.ValidatedFromAddress = ('hanessftest@gmail.com');    
}
    // If case type is “Sheridan,” insert the email template and set the from address
if (c.CaseNumber != null && c.Type.equals('Brand2')) { 
    sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId('00X0I000001GQezUAG');   // Set the template Id
    sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
    sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);
    emailMessage.ValidatedFromAddress = ('hanessftest1@gmail.com');    
}'''
```

Error Message at the moment when no case is assigned:[image]

Comment: you arw picking default then 0th.. if there would mutiple send eamil action then u might be messing with wrong action. so please check in ur code to validate ur action before applying template

Comment: Thank you Ayub - this pointed me down the right track

Comment: I'm glad i helped.